# Python - Issue with Downloader Middleware of settings.py in Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I implemented my own ProxyMiddleware class and RotateUserAgentMiddleware class. And made necessary changes in settings.py. Now, the problem is with assigning the values to the new elements in DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES  list. 
My code is behaving abnormally with values I have given, Can anyone please suggest me the proper way to assigning the values.

Here is my List:

```
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': None,
            'IpRotation.ProxyMiddleware.ProxyMiddleware': 800,
            'scrapy.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware' : None,
            'IpRotation.RotateUserAgentMiddleware.RotateUserAgentMiddleware':350
            }
```

When I disable this custom settings, everything goes fine. Unable to find the way to crack this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add your custom middleware

```
'IPProxy.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543
```

Comment: :Sorry for the dalay, Its throwing an error saying, exceptions.ImportError: No module named middlewares

Comment: Can you please explain me the use of middlewares.py module here. Because, I didn't use that module in my sample test case i.e., example explained in the scrapy official website, but still able to run that sample code well. Why?

Comment: The middlewares.py file is the request/response processing file. It is a low level plugin for globally altering the input or output. It has some specific function to do. It uses the middleware components which is associated with user's requests using sessions. Well this is complicated to understand though. If you are busy involved in a big project, I have nothing more to solve your problem, but if you are just in the starting portion of your project, I'll request you to transform to Django framework which will be much helpful and is user friendly too.

Comment: At any cost I need to complete it in scrapy itself. I am missing a silly thing to make my code work. The problem is with middleware settings itself.